# How to escape a backslash in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm writing a powershell program to replace strings using

```
-replace "$in", "$out"
```

It doesn't work for strings containing a backslash, how can I do to escape it?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more details about your code? (To escape the backslash you need to use double backslash : "\\" instead of "\".)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `-replace` operator uses regular expressions, which treat backslash as a special character. You can use double backslash to get a literal single backslash.

In your case, since you're using variables, I assume that you won't know the contents at design time. In this case, you should run it through `[RegEx]::Escape()`:

```
-replace [RegEx]::Escape($in), "$out"
```

That method escapes any characters that are special to regex with whatever is needed to make them a literal match (other special characters include `.`,`$`,`^`,`()`,`[]`, and more.

Comment: nice one Brian, thanx

Comment: Thank you for you anwser Brian

Comment: Ah, well done.  I'd forgotten about `Regex.Escape`.  This is a better solution than mine since PowerShell should unescape it correctly.

Comment: what about dot? (.) this one also gets escaped

Comment: @DmitryGusarov dot `.` is included in my non exhaustive list of characters, and it is also escaped by the recommended method.

Answer (score 11):

You'll need to either escape the backslash in the pattern with another backslash or use the `.Replace()` method instead of the `-replace` operator (but be advised they may perform differently):

```
PS C:\> 'asdf' -replace 'as', 'b'
bdf
PS C:\> 'a\sdf' -replace 'a\s', 'b'
a\sdf
PS C:\> 'a\sdf' -replace 'a\\s', 'b'
bdf
PS C:\> 'a\sdf' -replace ('a\s' -replace '\\','\\'), 'b'
bdf
```

Note that only the search pattern string needs to be escaped.  The code `-replace '\\','\\'` says, "replace the escaped pattern string `'\\'`, which is a single backslash, with the unescaped literal string `'\\'` which is two backslashes."

So, you should be able to use:

```
-replace ("$in" -replace '\\','\\'), "$out"
```

[Note: [briantist's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36749463/696808) is better.]

However, if your pattern has consecutive backslashes, you'll need to test it.

Or, you can use the `.Replace()` string method, but as I said above, it may not perfectly match the behavior of the `-replace` operator:

```
PS C:\> 'a\sdf'.replace('a\\s', 'b')
a\sdf
PS C:\> 'a\sdf'.replace( 'a\s', 'b')
bdf
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I have another question, what if the second argument of -replace had a backslash too, should I escape it by adding another backslash, for example this command :

PS C:\> 'a\sdf' -replace 'a\\s', 'b\\s'

it will render 'b\sdf'??

Comment: @ZakariaBelghiti The second string is taken literally.  The reason comes because the first argument of -replace is evaluated as a regular expression: `'asdf' -replace '[ad]', '1234'` returns `1234s1234f`.

Comment: @ZakariaBelghiti No problem.  However, briantist's solution with `-replace ([RegEx]::Escape($in)), "$out"` is better than mine.  If I'd remember that function, I'd have used it instead.